# How to capitalize the first letter of chapters in the table of Content?

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I am using the classic thesis style for my Ph.D. thesis and I have changed a little bit in the table of content, but I want to have the first letter of the chapters in uppercase but the outcome is in lower case. Any suggestion to change the letter to uppercase? I am using pdflatex, bibtex.

```
    \RequirePackage{silence} % :-\
    \WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Usage of package `titlesec'}
    %\WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Activating an ugly workaround}
    \WarningFilter{titlesec}{Non standard sectioning command detected}
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,%1headlines,
                headinclude,footinclude,cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt
                ]{scrreprt}

%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
\input{classicthesis-config}
%***************************
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american} % american ngerman
%\renewcommand*{\bibname}{new name}
%\setbibpreamble{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}


\include{Contents}

\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{Chapter01}
\include{Chapter02}

%*******************************************************
\end{document}
```

Here is the content.tex

```
%*******************************************************
% Table of Contents
%*******************************************************
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsc{\thesection}\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
%*******************************************************
% List of Figures and of the Tables
%*******************************************************
\clearpage
% \pagestyle{empty} % Uncomment this line if your lists should not have any headlines with section name and page number
\begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax
    %*******************************************************
    % List of Figures
    %*******************************************************
    %\phantomsection
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{\listfigurename}{lof}
    \listoffigures

    \vspace{8ex}

    %*******************************************************
    % List of Tables
    %*******************************************************
    %\phantomsection
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
    \listoftables

    \vspace{8ex}
    % \newpage

    %*******************************************************
    % List of Listings
    %*******************************************************
    %\phantomsection
%    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
%    \pdfbookmark[1]{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
%    \lstlistoflistings
%
    \vspace{8ex}

    %*******************************************************
    % Acronyms
    \clearpage
    %*******************************************************
   \pdfbookmark[1]{Acronyms}{acronyms}
    \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}
    \chapter*{Acronyms}

\endgroup
```

And I am posting all the packeages I used becuase I can not trace the problem.

```
[![% ****************************************************************************************************
% classicthesis-config.tex
% formerly known as loadpackages.sty, classicthesis-ldpkg.sty, and classicthesis-preamble.sty
% Use it at the beginning of your ClassicThesis.tex, or as a LaTeX Preamble
% in your ClassicThesis.{tex,lyx} with \input{classicthesis-config}
% ***************************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
  \usepackage{inputenc}

\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
 \usepackage{fontenc}


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 1. Configure classicthesis for your needs here, e.g., remove "drafting" below
% in order to deactivate the time-stamp on the pages
% (see ClassicThesis.pdf for more information):
% ****************************************************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{
  drafting=false,    % print version information on the bottom of the pages
  tocaligned=true, % the left column of the toc will be aligned (no indentation)
  dottedtoc=false,  % page numbers in ToC flushed right
  eulerchapternumbers=false, % use AMS Euler for chapter font (otherwise Palatino)
  linedheaders=false,       % chaper headers will have line above and beneath
  floatperchapter=true,     % numbering per chapter for all floats (i.e., Figure 1.1)
  eulermath=false,  % use awesome Euler fonts for mathematical formulae (only with pdfLaTeX)
  beramono=true,    % toggle a nice monospaced font (w/ bold)
  palatino=true,    % deactivate standard font for loading another one, see the last section at the end of this file for suggestions
  style=classicthesis % classicthesis, arsclassica
}{classicthesis}

%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{publication}{List of Publications}
% ****************************************************************************************************
% 2. Personal data and user ad-hoc commands (insert your own data here)
% ****************************************************************************************************
\newcommand{\myTitle}{Computational Trust \xspace}
%\newcommand{\mySubtitle}{An Homage to The Elements of Typographic Style\xspace}
%\newcommand{\myLocation}{Saarbrücken\xspace}
%\newcommand{\myTime}{June 2018\xspace}
%\newcommand{\myVersion}{\classicthesis}

% ********************************************************************
% Setup, finetuning, and useful commands
% ********************************************************************
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.}
\newcommand{\Ie}{I.\,e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g.}
\newcommand{\Eg}{E.\,g.}
% ****************************************************************************************************

% ****************************************************************************************************
% 3. Loading some handy packages
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Packages with options that might require adjustments
% ********************************************************************
\PassOptionsToPackage{dutch,american}{babel} % change this to your language(s), main language last
% Spanish languages need extra options in order to work with this template
%\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
  backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8, %instead of bibtex
  backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
  language=auto,%
  style=numeric-comp,%
  %style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
  %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
  sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
  maxbibnames=10, % default: 3, et al.
  %backref=true,%
  natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage\[numbers,sort&compress\]{natbib}
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}       % math environments and more by the AMS
  \usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
% ********************************************************************
% General useful packages
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag,epsfig} %
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right
\usepackage\[usenames,dvipsnames,table\]{xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!25}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}
 \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis
  %\renewcommand{\bflabel}\[1\]{{#1}\hfill} % fix the list of acronyms --> no longer working
  %\renewcommand*{\acsfont}\[1\]{\textsc{#1}}
  %\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}\[1\]{\acsfont{#1}}
  %\def\bflabel#1{{#1\hfill}}
\def\bflabel#1{{\acsfont{#1}\hfill}}
\def\aclabelfont#1{\acsfont{#1}}
 \usepackage\[ruled\]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\SubItem}\[1\]{
{\setlength\itemindent{15pt} \item\[-\] #1}
}
\setlist\[itemize\]{noitemsep, nolistsep}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
%\usepackage{xcolor,amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsfonts,bm,latexsym}
%%%\usepackage{quotchap}
%%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage\[ampersand\]{easylist}
%\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
%%\usepackage{flexisym}
%\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
% ****************************************************************************************************
%\usepackage{pgfplots} % External TikZ/PGF support (thanks to Andreas Nautsch)
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize\[mode=list and make, prefix=ext-tikz/\]
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 4. Setup floats: tables, (sub)figures, and captions
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs} % better tables
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}\[1\]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % to be used with each float for alignment
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}\[1\]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
% ****************************************************************************************************


% ****************************************************************************************************
% 5. Setup code listings
% ****************************************************************************************************
\usepackage{listings}
%\lstset{emph={trueIndex,root},emphstyle=\color{BlueViolet}}%\underbar} % for special keywords
\lstset{language=\[LaTeX\]Tex,%C++,
  morekeywords={PassOptionsToPackage,selectlanguage},
  keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},%\bfseries,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  %identifierstyle=\color{NavyBlue},
  commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\rmfamily,
  numbers=none,%left,%
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,%\tiny
  stepnumber=5,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  %frameround=ftff,
  %frame=single,
  belowcaptionskip=.75\baselineskip
  %frame=L
}
% ****************************************************************************************************




% ****************************************************************************************************
% 6. Last calls before the bar closes
% ****************************************************************************************************
% ********************************************************************
% Her Majesty herself
% ********************************************************************
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% titles in bold
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% page numbers in bold
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

% ********************************************************************
% Fine-tune hyperreferences (hyperref should be called last)
% ********************************************************************
\hypersetup{%
  %draft, % hyperref's draft mode, for printing see below
  colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,%
  % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
  %colorlinks=false, linktocpage=false, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV, pdfborder={0 0 0},%
  breaklinks=true, pageanchor=true,%
  pdfpagemode=UseNone, %
  % pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
  plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
  hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
  urlcolor=CTurl, linkcolor=CTlink, citecolor=CTcitation, pagecolor=RoyalBlue,
  urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, pagecolor=Black,%
  pdftitle={\myTitle},%
  pdfauthor={\textcopyright\ \myName},%
  pdfsubject={},%
  pdfkeywords={},%
  pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
  pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and classicthesis}%
}


% ********************************************************************
% Setup autoreferences (hyperref and babel)
% ********************************************************************
% There are some issues regarding autorefnames
% https://texfaq.org/FAQ-latexwords
% you have to redefine the macros for the
% language you use, e.g., american, ngerman
% (as chosen when loading babel/AtBeginDocument)
% ********************************************************************
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
  {%
    \addto\extrasamerican{%
      \renewcommand*{\figureautorefname}{Figure}%
      \renewcommand*{\tableautorefname}{Table}%
      \renewcommand*{\partautorefname}{Part}%
      \renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
      \renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
      \renewcommand*{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
      \renewcommand*{\subsubsectionautorefname}{Section}%
    }%
    \addto\extrasdutch{%
      \renewcommand*{\paragraphautorefname}{samenvatting }%
%      \renewcommand*{\subparagraphautorefname}{Unterabsatz}%
%      \renewcommand*{\footnoteautorefname}{Fu\"snote}%
%      \renewcommand*{\FancyVerbLineautorefname}{Zeile}%
%      \renewcommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Theorem}%
%      \renewcommand*{\appendixautorefname}{Anhang}%
%      \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}{Gleichung}%
%      \renewcommand*{\itemautorefname}{Punkt}%
    }%
      % Fix to getting autorefs for subfigures right (thanks to Belinda Vogt for changing the definition)
      \providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}%
    }{\relax}
\makeatother][1]][1]
```

Comment: How about you tell us what exactly you changed?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip I added these lines in the config.tex                  \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% titles in bold
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% page numbers in bold
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}'

Comment: @PhilipPirrip do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, I must say. You want them in small caps? Can you upload a screenshot of what you're getting and an example of what you want. Generally, if something is wrong, try removing your additions till you get the old behavior.